# Random forest, auc for training set and testing set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to tune my random forest classifier. When I use `GridSearchCV`, the best parameters are `min_samples_split = 2`, `min_samples_leaf = 4`, `max_depth = None`, which I think is definitely an overfit. So I plot the auc for both training and testing data:

[image: AUC vs depth]

The graph shows that as we increase the `max_depth`, both train_auc and test_auc will increase; does that graph make sense? Because I think at some point as we increase the depth, the performance of testing data will actually go down.

Comment: maybe this https://medium.com/all-things-ai/in-depth-parameter-tuning-for-random-forest-d67bb7e920d can help you
your diagram makes sense, when score of train data and test data start to split, you can early stop model and pick good max_depth which in your case can be `5`

Comment: Hi@mjrezaee, but isn't that higher AUC on testing set means better performance of the model? Should I just a model which not overfit but has low AUC or a model which overfitted but has higher AUC on test set?

Comment: `RandomForestClassifier` trains with Accuracy score and it's better to use this score to measure early stop point. You may see the split point more clearly when Train Accuracy error (1-accuracy_score) keep reducing but Test accuracy error starts to increase.
although you can see that in AUC diagram, train score keeps increasing while you have almost instant test score and 0.15 is considered noticeable difference in AUC measurement

Comment: @mjrezaee, `RandomForestClassifier` trains to minimize log-loss, not accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to restrict "max_depth" in order to avoid overfitting. This rectrict should be your intuition . Therefore , my advice is read this https://medium.com/all-things-ai/in-depth-parameter-tuning-for-random-forest-d67bb7e920d . Maybe it will help you

Comment: Thanks! From other examples online, I see there is always an optimal value for test set AUC, but in my case, it seems going for higher 'max_depth' always will turn a better AUC for test data, despite the overfit. Same for 'min_sample_split', lower value always gives better performance on test data. Is that normal? or there is something wrong with my model/data?

Comment: I am thinking the data is normal so i think there is no something wrong and  that is normal because as the number of branches increases, it will begin to customize for each data, that is, to give better results. But we don't want this because that causes overfitting the data.Therefore we try find a good threshold for max_depth etc.                Note: I do not have enough experience to generalize, I write with my limited knowledge.

Comment: my understanding of overfit is that you are using too complicated model so that the performance of training data is good, but the performance of testing data is poor. why in my case when the model is overfitted, the AUC of testing data still getting better?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-an-AUC-in-test-data-less-than-an-AUC-in-training-data-mean

Answer (score 0):

You are right to expect large `max_depth` will lead to overfitting and eventually decreasing test scores.  However, as your plot shows, that doesn't happen with your data until after depth 14.  You say that the optimal `max_depth` is `None`, i.e. a full-depth tree, which *is* quite surprising, but we'd need to know more about your data, search space, etc. to say much more.

Now, in some circumstances the test score is not the only consideration, and you may want to consider a smaller `max_depth` than the one that gives optimal test score.  See e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/66350/55122.  So, looking at your plot, perhaps you'd prefer depth around 10, as a potentially-more-stable if slightly-less-performant model.